# Prevent Un-Installation of of app

Tags: ios, uninstallation

Okay so I was wondering if it is possible that user can not uninstall the app from iphone without a password ?

For example If I have an app and I have set a special password inside the app to prevent uninstallation. So that If any one gets my device they could not un-install the app without enetring that specific password ?

Comment: No, you cannot stop user form deleting the app.

Comment: Isn't that what the device's password is for?

Comment: Lets Say I want to create a parental control app which would be installed on the child's iphone. And I want to prevent the child from uninstalling the app. How would I do that if possible ?

Comment: At the end it is still another app on iphone. And you cannot stop user from deleting the app.

Comment: Parental control and the sort of management you are looking for is provided via MDM and device supervision. It can be done but not by an app alone. You need a provide the profiles and the management commands

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. A user can uninstall any app. The app is not run. There is nothing the app can do to prevent itself from being removed.

Comment: So we can not create a parental control app for iphone ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that exactly. Besides what you asked in your question, what other functionality do you mean exactly?

Comment: Actually I was brain storming for creating an app for some kind of parental control. For example if parents install my app on their child's phone to track some activites. In that way child can uninstall the app. and whole purpose of app will be gone.

Comment: Nope, can't be done. iOS provide parental control through restrictions. That's it. A 3rd party app can't provide any of that type of control. Each app is in its own sandbox. It can't do anything to other apps.